# File input jQuery change event fires only once

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, file-upload, jquery-events

I have use plugin ref:- [http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-upload-files-with-codeigniter-and-ajax--net-21684][1]

I am trying to do fix 3 images uploading program using jQuery ajax. That's why I make some changes according to requirements some of them are:-

1. I convert all CSS style from id to class means (# to .)
2. replace `dataType` from JSON to string
3. change pic upload event from submit to file input change event

**Everything is works fine, Image uploaded and display in view also done successfully**

Now my problem is **file input change event fires only once**. What's the problem in my code?
Please help me to fix this problem.

View:-

```
<div class="photobox fL">
      <div class="container" title="Choose File">
          <div class="doit">
               <img src="&lt;?php echo base_url();?&gt;images/thumb-5.jpg" id="img1" alt="Upload Photo" width="220px" height="300px;"/>
          </div>    
          <input id="file1" class="hid" name="file1" type="file" size="1/">
      </div>
</div>
```

site.js:- (external)

```
$(function() {
      $('#file1').change(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $.ajaxFileUpload({
            url :'./upload_image/upload_file/', 
            secureuri :false,
            fileElementId :'file1',
            dataType :'string',
            success : function (path)  //EXECUTES SUCCESSFULLY
            {
               var base_url=loadName();
               var img1 = document.getElementById("img1");
               img1.src = base_url+path; //CHANGE IMG SRC WITH NEW UPLOADED IMAGE SUCCESSFULLY
            }
      });
      return false;
    });
});
```

and my controller also works fine. Problem is file input change event occurs only once.
I do not use form tag because I am not doing uploading process on submit event as tells in reference. But still my image uploading works fine at once only because next time change event not fires

Please help me out from this problem.

Comment: try to use it $(document).on('change','#file1',function(e){}); directly with out $(function(){}); and you can use .on or .bind method also

Comment: try resetting the file input element after you done uploading successfully.

Comment: thanks @Rocky you solved my problem I want to accept your answer but I can not find option to accept comment as a answer thanks again

Answer (score 1):

**When you add an image and try to upload the same image again change event not firing because of the value of input don't change, you should clear the input's value at the end of process **

```js
$('#imageUpload').on('change', function handleImage(e) {
            //some process
            // then clear the value
            $(this).val(null);
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

**You should try it on dynamically created elements:**
both the events are works .on or .bind for example:

```
$(document).on('change','#file1',function(e)
{
              e.preventDefault();
              $.ajaxFileUpload({
                    url :'./upload_image/upload_file/', 
                    secureuri :false,
                    fileElementId :'file1',
                    dataType :'string',
                    success : function (path)  //EXECUTES SUCCESSFULLY
                    {
                       var base_url=loadName();
                       var img1 = document.getElementById("img1");
                       img1.src = base_url+path; //CHANGE IMG SRC WITH NEW UPLOADED IMAGE SUCCESSFULLY
                    }
              });
              return false;
});
```